# how to upload image with ajax and codeigniter where my CI is IN var/www/html

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

In html file upload is in form like this

```
   <form method="post" action="" enctype = "multipart/form-data" ><label> File Input: </label><input type = "file" name = "userfile" id="userfile"><a href = "http://localhost/upload_img/index.php/upload/do_upload" >Submit </a></form>
```

in my controller:

```
    <?php class Upload extends CI_Controller {
       public function index(){
          $this->load->view('upload_view');
       }
       public function do_upload(){
       $config = array(
            'upload_path' => "http://localhost/upload_img/index.php/uploads/",
         'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf"
        );
        //print_r($config);
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            print_r($data);
        }
        else
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            print_r( $error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i got error as output : Array ( [error] =>
You did not select a file to upload.

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changes**

1. `<form>` action filed is set
2. Submitting data with `<input type="submit"`
3. `upload_path` Modified

---

Try this

**In View**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() ;?>index.php/upload/do_upload" enctype = "multipart/form-data" >
      <label> File Input: </label>
      <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

**In Controller**

```
class Upload extends CI_Controller {

   public function index(){
      $this->load->view('upload_view');
   }

   public function do_upload()
   {

       $config = array(
            'upload_path' => "./uploads/",
            'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|doc|docx"
        );

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            print_r( $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            print_r($data);
        }
    }
}
```

> > **If you using Ubuntu OS. Then give 777 permission to upload folder.**

Comment: thank you so much.. I Got Output as i want. but can you help me how can i pass this userfile to ajax through controller. how can i store userfile into ajax variable> note that i have so many field in my html form.

Comment: @NishitaPatel check this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax--net-21684

Comment: @NishitaPatel http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues with your form code!!

You are not supposed to use anchor tag on Submit, it should either be a `<button>` tag or `<input>` tag with attribute `type="submit"`

Please see this:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax--net-21684

Answer (score 0):

First of all correct your form like this:
**View:**

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/upload_img/index.php/upload/do_upload" enctype = "multipart/form-data" >
      <label> File Input: </label>
      <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){
       $this->load->view('upload_view');
    }

    public function do_upload(){
       $config = array(
            'upload_path' => "uploads/",
            'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf"
        );
        //print_r($config);
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            print_r($data);
        }
        else
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            print_r( $error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will doing as you send code but sill i got error: Array ( [error] =>
The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable.

)

Comment: This is folder permission error. before upload or write make sure upload folder have write permission (0775) to access. You can give access by ssh.